# Updating to android studio 3.1 and gradle 4.4 gives cannot resolve symbol error for some dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.1

I just installed android studio 3.1 and updated gradle to 4.4 and now some dependencies like volley and materialmenu are linted red with error "can not resolve symbol"  but project compiles and runs!
Any ideas?
Downloading dependency from git and putting it in a module works but i can't do it for all libraries one by one

Edit
I could fixed error on volley by changing volley verson from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0 but some other libraries still have the problem.

**Solved**

**Updating to gradle 4.6 solved the problem.**

**Update:** 
if upgrading gradle to 4.6 didn't work try deleting .idea/libraries folder and invalidate catch/restart android studio

Comment: thanks. 4.6 did not solve my problem but I started upgrading library versions to latest and the issues were resolved.

Comment: I had the exact same problme with `joda-time`. I *downgraded* it from `2.9.9` to `2.9.8`, the lints were cleared to my surprise, so I reverted back to `2.9.9`. Still, I see no false positive lints.... pretty weird.